# Align DIV horizonatlly with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to align 2 DIVs horizontally with CSS in my [Website], basically the Log in DIV is a bit higher than the Register DIV[1]
[![Problem with 2 DIVs][2]][2]

CSS where I need help:

```
.woocommerce-form.woocommerce-form-login.login {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}    

.woocommerce form.register {
    border: 1px solid #d3ced2;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 2em 0;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
```

What am I missing here?
Thank you for your help!
[1]: https://localchain.co.uk/my-account/
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReVr6.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With below CSS settings, the login and register section will be aligned.

```
.u-column1.col-1,
.u-column2.col-2 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.woocommerce-form.woocommerce-form-login.login {
    /* width: 50%; */
    /* float: left; */
}

.woocommerce form.checkout_coupon, .woocommerce form.login, .woocommerce form.register {
    border: 1px solid #d3ced2;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 2em 0;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    /* float: right; */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Really saved me! It works perfectly! I just realized that I was getting the wrong selector as well! should just select the u-columns :D Thank you @yinsweet

Comment: @LuisSamouco glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it is because of `margin` property which you only have at `register` div.

```
 margin: 2em 0;
```

If you remove that, both will be at the same starting distance.

Comment: I have fixed it already! Thank you @Gibbs :D